# I want to move image button?

Tags: java, android, xml, image

I want to move image button which I am using in my quadcoptor app but I can't move the image button I tried many things but its not moving !!

This is my UPDATED java code
It works to move the image button in a specific circumference but when I touch the button and drag it from center the button goes unstable and flicker around!!

```
 x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();

                float dX = x - idx;
                float dY = y - idy;
                double angleInDegrees = Math.atan(dY / dX) * 360 / 3.14;

                idx = x;
                idy = y;

                imknob.setTranslationX((float)(200*(Math.cos(angleInDegrees))));
                imknob.setTranslationY((float)(200*(Math.sin(angleInDegrees))));
```

I don't know where I am getting wrong !! help someone to make it right!!

And this is the XML code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:id="@id/rootie" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#000000">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/home" android:background="#FF000000" android:visibility="visible" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="730dp" android:layout_height="473dp" android:src="@drawable/background" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_x="-13dp"
        android:layout_y="-70dp" />
    <ImageView android:id="@id/g_on" android:background="#00000000" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/g_on" android:layout_x="504dp" android:layout_y="45dp" />
    <ImageView android:id="@id/g_off" android:background="#00000000" android:visibility="visible" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/g_off" android:layout_x="507dp" android:layout_y="45dp" />

  <ImageButton android:id="@id/stk2" android:background="#00000000" android:visibility="visible" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/stk2" android:layout_x="422dp" android:layout_y="126dp" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@id/stk1_" android:background="#00000000" android:visibility="visible" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/stk1" android:layout_x="163dp" android:layout_y="52dp" />

  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/stk3" android:background="#00000000" android:visibility="invisible" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/stk2" android:layout_x="422dp" android:layout_y="123dp" />

  <ImageView android:id="@id/pwroff" android:background="#00000000" android:visibility="visible" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/signal_" android:layout_x="281dp" android:layout_y="219dp" android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
    <ImageView android:id="@id/pwron" android:background="#00000000" android:visibility="invisible" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/signal" android:layout_x="261dp" android:layout_y="187dp" android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />

  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/back" android:background="#00000000" android:visibility="visible" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/back" android:layout_x="122dp" android:layout_y="11dp" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@id/stk1" android:background="#00000000" android:visibility="visible" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/stk1" android:layout_x="165dp" android:layout_y="242dp" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[This is the UI of my quadcoptor app I want to move the red dot knob which acts as a controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JltK.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set the knob's position to be the position of the touch event. Instead of setting float variables

```
x = event.getX();
y = event.getY();
```

you should be setting the variables of your knob.

```
imknob.layout_x = event.getX();
imknob.layout_y = event.getY();
```

Even still, I am not sure that is the best way to move the button. You should probably store the starting position of the button, then store the start of the the press, and with each move of the touch move the button equally, then when the touch is finished, move the button back to its starting position.

Comment: still can't move the image button !! I tried many different codes but it does not move !! It gets the touch event but the image button does not move!!

Comment: I have never used layout_x and layout_y to position an element, maybe you can try setting the X-value 
    imknob.setX(event.getX())
or using a translation manipulation.